# Yii2 kartik datepicker multiple inline

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, widget, inline

I want a Datepicker inline with multidate enabled.

It is rendered correctly but returns only the last selected date.

Return value: `'12.11.2016'`

If I set `'type'` to `TYPE_INPUT` everything is working fine.

Expected return Value: `'23.11.2016, 24.11.2016, 18.11.2016, 12.11.2016'`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'dateString')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'multidate' => true,

            ],
        ]);
?>
```

I'm using `"kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev"` and the model is a ActiveRecord Model.

Comment: It is unfortunate that currently no workaround is there in the plugin and also when I noticed the source code the current code flow makes it difficult to do the changes.I deleted my answer and let us hope the makers of the plugin comes up with a fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been fixed with this commit: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker/commit/39e0e71277d0f115341e118a2b879a0dfcbd01c3

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'date_time')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                            'options' => [
                              'value' => "Jul-11-2020,Jul-14-2021,Jul-12-2020",
                                'class' => "col-md-12 form-control picker"
                            ],
                            'readonly' => false,
                            'language' => 'en',
                            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'format' => 'M-dd-yyyy',
                                'todayHighlight' => true,
                                'multidate' => true,
                            ],
                        ]);
```